# Do roots of polynomial with coefficients in a CM field lie in a CM field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields, number-fields

This is something that I have been thinking about for a while now, not sure if it is standard (or even true at all) or not:

Let $K/ \mathbb Q$ be a CM number field, that is, it is closed under complex conjugation, which induces an automorphism that commutes with the other $\mathbb Q$-embeddings of $K$ into the field of complex numbers. Let $P(z) \in K[z]$ be irreducible and monic. Will the splitting field of $P$ over $K$ be CM? If not, does there exist a CM field containing the roots of $P$?

Can we say something if $K/\mathbb Q$ is Galois and CM (so complex conjugation commutes with the rest of the Galois group)?

Partial progress(?):

If $\alpha_1, \cdots , \alpha_d$ denote the roots of $P(z):=\sum_{j=0}^d a_jz^j \in K[z]$ lying in some splitting field $E/K$, then Vieta's relaions tell us that $a_j = (-1)^{n-j}e_j(\alpha_1, \cdots , \alpha_d)$ where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th symmetric function. Thus for any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)$, we have
$$(-1)^{n-j} e_j(\overline{\sigma\alpha_1}, \cdots ,\overline{\sigma\alpha_d}) = \overline{\sigma a_j} = \sigma({\overline{a_j}}) = (-1)^{n-j} e_j(\sigma(\overline\alpha_1), \cdots , \sigma(\overline\alpha_d))$$
Since the tuples $\{\overline{\sigma\alpha_1}, \cdots ,\overline{\sigma\alpha_d}\}$ and $\{\sigma(\overline\alpha_1), \cdots , \sigma(\overline\alpha_d)\}$ have equal values of elementary symmetric functions, they must be roots of the same polynomial and hence must be equal *upto permutation*. What I want however is that $(\overline{\sigma\alpha_1}, \cdots ,\overline{\sigma\alpha_d}) = (\sigma(\overline\alpha_1), \cdots , \sigma(\overline\alpha_d))$, the equality holding as ordered tuples.

Maybe I am missing something really simple but the observation that I just obtained also makes me fear that a counterexample might also be constructible (no pun intended) by just enforcing these conditions, although I haven't been able to construct the same. If none of these hold, can we say something along these lines under some (hopefully minor) additional conditions? I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

**Edit:** So I've already asked this in a comment, but I feel like it is more appropriate a an edit. As Prof. KConrad has pointed out, there is a very simple counterexample. That leads me to ask the following:
Is there anything we can say concerning the relationship between $\sigma\overline\alpha$ and $\overline{\sigma\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ which is a root of a monic irreducible polynomial with coefficients in a CM field $K$ (where $\sigma$ is some $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of a finite Galois extension over $K$ containing the conjugates of $\alpha$)? What about when we impose conditions on $\sigma$? Or on $\alpha$ (like say, $\alpha$ has to be an algebraic integer)? I might be naive to expect this, in which case I would appreciate some examples suggesting very erratic behaviour.

**Edit 2:** I suppose a more precise reformulation of the question asked in the above edit might be the following: what we can say about the size (absolute value) of the element $|(\sigma\tau - \tau\sigma)\alpha|$ where $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ are as above and $\tau$ is complex conjugation.

Comment: Let $K = \mathbf Q(i)$, which is Galois over $\mathbf Q$, and set $P(z) = z^2-(1+2i)$. The splitting field of $P(z)$ over $K$ is $K(\sqrt{1+2i})$.  The field $K(\sqrt{1+2i})$ is not CM since its degree over $\mathbf Q$ is 4 and the only quadratic field inside it is $K$, which is not totally real.

Comment: Very nice and simple counterexample, thank you sir! Is there anything we can say concerning the relationship between $\sigma\overline\alpha$ and $\overline{\sigma\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ which is a root of a monic irreducible polynomial with coefficients in a CM field $K$ (where $\sigma$ is some automorphism of a finite Galois extension over $K$ containing the conjugates of $\alpha$)? What about when we impose some condition on $\sigma$? Or on $\alpha$ (like say, $\alpha$ has to be an algebraic integer)?